# Open in new tab redirecting to login page

Tags: angular

I'm trying to open my screen in a new tab. It always redirects me to the login screen. What should I do to allow users open in new tab?

I tried to update my localstorage variable during login and clear it during logout. But that didnt help.

This is my login.component :

```
login() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.setProvinceCode(this.model.province);
    this.authenticationError = false;
    this.validationMessage = "";

    this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password, this.model.province)
        .subscribe(
            (user: any) => {
                if (user && user.authenticated) {
                    if (this.rememberMe) {
                        this.appStorageService.setData(this.appStorageService.usernameKey, this.model.username);

                    } else {
                        this.appStorageService.removeData(this.appStorageService.usernameKey);
                    }

                    if (this.model.province !== 'BC') {
                        this.appStorageService.setData(this.appStorageService.mustChangePasswordInNextLoginKey, user.mustChangePasswordInNextLogin);
                    }

                }
                else if (user.message) {
                    this.validationMessage = user.message;
                }
                else {
                    this.authenticationError = true;
                }

                this.loading = false;
            },
            error => {
                this.alertService.error(error);
                this.loading = false;
            });
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more information or code? Does your browser have the local storage value when you open it in the new tab? What does your ````this.model```` contain? Does your application have an auth guard?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to check if the local storage has value ? This is my this.model code.
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    model: { province: string, username: string, password: string } = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        province: ''
    };
    loading = false;
    returnUrl: string;
    rememberMe = false;
    authenticationError = false;
    validationMessage = "";
Yes, the application has an auth gaurd.
Whenever I try to paste the url in the same tab it opens my home page and not the specific page. Any other code I need to add?

Comment: My localstorage doesn't have values in it. So should I try to provide values for it? if so could you please tell me how to do that?